# Choose IP when sending mail in php

Tags: php, email, ip

My server has 2 IPs.

Whenever I send an email in php using `mail()` the IP used to send the email is IP A. However, I'd like to use IP B.

Is this possible?

If yes, is this possible using `mail()` ?

If yes, how?

Comment: I think the scenario of my question is a little different form the question which this was marked a duplicate of (or at least more specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible: unless you are using a SMTP server, your own server (so the one running your PHP script) is used to send mails. And if that server is configured to use IP A, your mail is sent through that IP.

Comment: So I'd have to reconfigure the server in order to use IP B with `mail()`?

Comment: Thats one option - or use a proper SMTP server to connect to instead of using `mail`

Comment: Well, this is the right answer to my question I think. Thanks